# Why can't a self signed applet on an FTP server connect to a MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, database, applet

I'm working on an applet uploaded to an ftp server. That applet should connect to a MySQL database (Which should be on the same server as far as I know).

Note: The applet is self signed.

- If I'm running the applet locally it works fine.
- If I launch the applet locally from a web browser it also works perfectly.
- But when I upload it to the ftp server and launch it from it's website, it freezes at line 4 (The DriverManager.getConnection() method)

.

```
public static void initConnection(final Settings info) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + info.getHost() + ":3306/" + info.getDbName(),
                    info.getUser(), info.getPass());
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the computer on which the applet is executed hasn't a firewall blocking access to MySQL's port (3306 here) ? And are you sure your mysql server accepts distant connection for this user ? I've never seen a sql server in production configured to let enter connections from any internet point.

Comment: @dystroy I am using the same computer in all 3 tries described above.It's only while uploaded to the server that it won't work.

Comment: Rene, you do realize that the applet is running on the remote computer, the one with the browser, not on the server with MySQL database, don't you?

Comment: @Olaf Indeed. I am using the correct hostname (as in not Localhost) to connect to it. Unless that's not what you meant.

Comment: How is `info` populated? Is it read from a properties file?

Comment: @elgaton It's filled from an encrypted text file packed inside the .jar file. The file is decrypted and `info` is populated. I have checked and the right information is filled in no matter how I launch the applet.

Comment: @RenéJensen Have you tried running Wireshark to see if the applet opens the connection or not?

Comment: @elgaton Wireshark doesn't catch any packets while running the applet from the ftp server. It does while running it locally.

Comment: @RenéJensen Try running the applet using AppletViewer like this: `appletviewer -J-Djava.security.debug=access,failure http://url.to.the.page/`. This will print a log of all security-related events - I still think something is going wrong there.

Comment: @elgaton As I only really have experience with Netbeans I tried adding it to the command line there. Although the ,failure and url part didn't work. It said the url was a class it couldn't find. When I did use it, it printed a ton of "access: access allowed" for just about everything (Including socket connection)

Comment: @RenéJensen Could you please run the command from a terminal (use the right URL, of course), post the output to Pastebin and give a link here?

Comment: @Elgaton Here you go: http://pastebin.com/i1gWsB1y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I have answered this myself. The problem was that from trying to connect to the database, to have a full working connection took about 3 minutes or so. Technically this question was void all along. I'll see if I can find out why it's so slow and ask another question if I can't find it.

So once again, it had nothing to do with policies or permissions. Just being slow as hell for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's always painful when users let a question open and don't take the time to give back an explanation to the many people who wondered about a problem. Don't hesitate to add the slowness explanation when you find it. And accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because, when you run the applet from the server, the Java Plug-in imposes a strict sandbox to prevent malicious actions from being performed. One of these is establishing connections to other computers.

Just write a policy file allowing connections to port 3306 of your database host (use `policytool` to generate it; you'll need to grant the `java.net.SocketPermission` permission, with the `resolve` and `connect` actions, for the DB host), then embed it into the JAR and, in the code, create a security manager using that file ([here](http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-security/606/Policy-file-in-a-Jar) is a sample).

EDIT: I noticed from the AppletViewer log that the decryption classes you use need another permission not granted by default when the code is launched from a remote location. Follow the technique above, but grant the permission `java.lang.RuntimePermission` (action: `accessClassInPackage.sun.misc`) as well and you should be fine.

Comment: Does self signing an applet not give it permission to do whatever it wants to, as long as the user accepts it?

Comment: You're right on that (the only exception is when JavaScript code accesses the applet, see <http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html>).

Comment: @RenéJensen It seems the applet requires other permissions as well, see updated answer.